# Кроссплатформенность Python

Tags: python, кроссплатформенность

Можно ли назвать Python кроссплатформенным? Всегда ли так? Кроссплатформенность и переносимость программ это одно и то же?

Comment: Язык программирования как таковой - вообще вещь абстрактная. Реализации языка (например, CPython, PyPy, Micropython) могут быть скомпилированы для какого-то набора платформ (но не для всех в принципе существующих). Программа на языке программирования может быть кроссплатформенной, если не использует какие-то специфические для конкретной платформы возможности или библиотеки.

Comment: Это вопрос для учебного задания или для понимания? Потому что в такой постановке можно ответить "да" и это будет правильно. И можно ответить "нет" и это тоже будет правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Назвать можно, но не совсем. Отдельный файл будет кроссплатформеным, но интерпретаторы на разных платформах разные.

*Кроссплатформенность и переносимость программ это одно и то же?* - зависит от автора учебника.